# RedirectMatch redirect every url to https except few urls

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, httpd, mod-proxy, tomcat

At present I am redirecting all http urls to https urls using the following directive,

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://someserver.com$1
```

Now I am stuck with an scenario where I have to redirect *everything except* the URLs like http://someserver.com/test or http://someserver.com/test/users or basically anything that has a /test followed by anything in it.

Also, I want to redirect these urls that have a "/test.." to be a normal http to show an access denied page(a html page). To add on to the complication all requests that go through "/" are routed to tomcat via ajp using the `<Location />` and `ProxyPass` directives

I am forced to use only RedirectMatch in this case basically because if I have to use Rewrite I have to change a lot of other configurations.

Could we have multiple RedirectMatch? If so, how can I configure the regex for the scenario above...

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead:

```
RedirectMatch permanent (^((?!test).)*)$  https://someserver.com$1
```

Comment: The redirect of URLs that does not have "test" in it results in 404..I guess the redirect isn't working properly...

Comment: try this  `^(((?!test).)*)$` result of this redirection is:    `somesite.com/test/me = somesite.com/test/me`,  `somesite.com/folder/me = anothersite.com/somesite.com/niodest/me`

Comment: I think what I would want is - everything that *does not match* http://somesite.com/test or http://somesite/test/.... followed by anything to be redirected to their https equvalents(eg https://somesite/nontest to https://somesite/nontest..)